# Can a jar file contain a RAT or KeyLogger on Linux?

Tags: java, security, jar, remote-access, keylogger

I'm working in a freelancing project with a company which has their own time tracking and screenshoting application.

They've sent me a `.jar` file which seems to be legit and does what it says. However I'm afraid not lose my accounts or anything in meantime.

I have tried running the jar file with `-Djava.security.manager` and it crashes like so:

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "user.home" "read")
```

Am I safe from keylogging and other things or should I consider working inside a virtual machine for this project?

Is there any way to check?

Comment: A JAR file could absolutely include malicious code.  As for how to check, I'm not a java expert, sorry.
if you are that concerned, yes migrate into a VM.

Comment: As far as you are .jar file doesnt run as root or doesnt require root access, its safe to run it

Comment: consider .jar to be an archive file containing classes and other java resources. JAR = Java Archive

Comment: Thank you for the answers. My real concern is, can it somehow still run after the application is closed?

Comment: It depends what you mean by “closed.”  If you close the window, the Java program may still be running.  However, if there are no active processes named `java` or `java.exe`, the program is not running and cannot do anything malicious.  In general, Java programs cannot log keystrokes in other applications, but they can certainly delete/overwrite your files.

Answer (score 0):

consider .jar to be an archive file containing classes and other java resources. JAR = Java Archive.

So yes it can have a key logger or any other malicious file.

java command to create a jar looks like this

> jar cf jar-file input-file(s)  [Creating a JAR File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html)

If you would have noticed it(the jar) can also include binary files specific to OS sometime

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My real concern is, can it somehow still run after the application is closed?

Comment: I may not be the best person to answer how a malicious code works. In case it is a java class file then you may say it will not execute if jar is not running. But if the key logger is another program written in any other language it can still run. Moreover there are background processes and daemons which once started can continue to run even when the parent process has closed out.